# Gson parse array of array with key

Tags: java, json, gson

This is my base object:

```
class Obj
{
  float t;
  String data;
  int y;
}

json example: {"t": 11.0,  "data": "7432",  "y": 0 }
```

I need to parse in java, using Gson, an input like this:

```
{
 "key1":[{"t": 4.0,  "data": "saer",  "y": 0 },..,{"t": 6.6,  "data": "dfs",  "y": 4 }],
 "key2":[{"t": 33,50,  "data": "3r2",  "y": 1 },...,{"t": 43.0,  "data": "54t",  "y": 3 }],
 ...
}
```

In PHP i'm using this script:

```
    $decoded = json_decode($_POST['json']);             
    foreach ($decoded as $key => $single)
    {
        foreach ($single as $value) 
        {   
            // using $key, $value->t,...
        }           
    }
```

How can I do the same thing in java? I'm confused how retrive the "key" values.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple way you can parse it as

```
final Type typeOf= new TypeToken<Map<String,List<Obj>>>(){}.getType();
final Map<String,List<Obj>> map = new Gson().fromJson(Your_Json_String, typeOf);
// get value 
final  List<Obj> list = map.get("key1");
```